# How to get a value of particular field inside loop Django

Tags: django

I want to print values of 'sm' inside loop

```
alist = [
 {'price': '700', 'sizes': {'sm': True, 'md': False, 'lg': True, 'xl': True} },
 {'price': '900', 'sizes': {'sm': False, 'md': True, 'lg': True, 'xl': True} }
]

for i in alist :
   print(i.get('sizes'['sm']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Revise print code.

```
alist = [
 {'price': '700', 'sizes': {'sm': True, 'md': False, 'lg': True, 'xl': True} },
 {'price': '900', 'sizes': {'sm': False, 'md': True, 'lg': True, 'xl': True} }
]

for i in alist :
   print(i['sizes']['sm'])
```

Comment: Thank you soo much